# How I can limit the introduced digits in the cell of the datagridview?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I want to create a datagridview that only accept numbers (Integers or doubles). When the number is double, I only want to save 2 digits after the point. (E.g. 1.22) and automatically change the cell. I create an event to make this.

I was able to get a working event but when I put the number with 2 digits after the point, the last digit doesn’t appear in the cell and the cell change.
When I’m debugging with a breakpoint in the line “dgvDatos[column, row].Value = txtInCell;”  . The variable txtInCell (is used to see what is written in the cell )  has the correct/complete value .

```
   void dText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {           

        bool dot;
        if (txtInCell.Contains(".") == true)
            dot = true;
        else
            dot = false;
        //Only accept numbers
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '.')
                if (!dot)
                {
                    txtInCell += e.KeyChar;
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
                else
                    e.Handled = true;
            else
                txtInCell += e.KeyChar;
            if (txtInCell.Contains("."))
            {
                int row = dgvDatos.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int column = dgvDatos.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                string[] elements = txtInCell.Split('.');
                if (elements[1].Length > 1)
                {
                    dgvDatos[column, row].Value = txtInCell;
                    dgvDatos.CurrentCell = this.dgvDatos[column + 1, row];
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //Use backspace as control
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
                txtInCell = txtInCell.Remove(txtInCell.Length - 1);
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //all the other keys are disabled
            e.Handled = true;
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use validate event

```
 dataGridView1.CellValidating += (s, eargs) => eargs.Cancel = !new Regex(@"^\d*(.\d|.\d\d)$").IsMatch(eargs.FormattedValue.ToString());
```

You can also give a tooltip about why you are not allowing the user to enter the value like you cannot enter more than two decimal digits etc you can also add some coloring flashing to add more spice

Comment: it doesn’t work As I expected. I need that the selection cell Change automatically when I introduce a valide format (the second decimal) and I need be able to change the cell. The validating event stops the change of the cell.